# how to rewrite link with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've function like this

```
function get_lang($url){
    $lang = explode("/", $url);
    $bahasa = array();
    $bahasa['url_id'] = '';
    $bahasa['url_en'] = '';
    if(in_array('id', $lang)){
      $bahasa['lang'] = "id";
      $bahasa['url_id'] = $url;
      $key = array_search('id', $lang);
      $lang[$key] = "en";
      $i=0;
      foreach($lang as $link){
        if($i==0){
          $bahasa['url_en'] .= $link;
        }else{
          $bahasa['url_en'] .= '/'.$link;
        }
        $i++;
      }

      return $bahasa;
    }

    if(in_array('en', $lang)){
      $bahasa['lang'] = "en";
      $bahasa['url_en'] = $url;
      $key = array_search('en', $lang);
      $lang[$key] = "id";
      $i=0;
      foreach($lang as $link){
        if($i==0){
          $bahasa['url_id'] .= $link;
        }else{
          $bahasa['url_id'] .= '/'.$link;
        }
        $i++;
      }

      return $bahasa;
    }

    return $bahasa;
  } 
$language = get_lang($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and my home.php

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="?lang=">

<select name="menu1" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">

<?php
if(($language['lang'] == "id") || (empty($language['lang']))) {
?>

<option value="id" selected>ID</option>
<option value="en">EN</option>

<?php
} else {
?>

<option value="id">ID</option>
<option value="en" selected>EN</option>

<?php
} // end else
?>

</select>
```

and my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=home [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=pages&idp=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=pages&idp=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=category&idc=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=category&idc=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^detailpost/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=detailpost&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^detailpost/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=detailpost&id=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery$ index.php?mod=gallery [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=gallery&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?mod=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^search-result/$ index.php?mod=searchresult [L]
RewriteRule ^search-result/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=searchresult&search=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-result/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=searchresult&search=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?mod=login [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?mod=register [L]
RewriteRule ^maintenance$ maintenance.php [L]
```

when i open myweb with default language id and choose option id/en its work, the problem is when i click other page like myweb/pages/about-us or other, thats all just show home.php

how to fix it?

i want to where i click myweb/pages/about-us become myweb/pages/about-us/en or myweb/pages/about-us/id

thanks for the answer and sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove a few characters (`/([^/]*)`) from one of your `pages` rewrite rule, similar to how all of your other rewrite rules already are.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=home [L]
-RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=pages&idp=$1 [L]
+RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=pages&idp=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=pages&idp=$1&page=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=category&idc=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=category&idc=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @cnst, i've do it and not work
when i go to myweb/pages/about-us that still show home.php and i try to choose option to en, page still show home.php and ilnk become mysite/pages/en

Comment: I don't see how your edit addresses my question of what's not working.